# Get more visitors in Krustyland

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

In the Simpson's Tapped Out, how do I get more people walking around the amusement park? I'm not talking about the Simpson's characters that also appear in Springfield, I'm talking about the random characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the star rating (your Krust-O-Meter) of your Krustyland increases, you'll get more visitors.

Comment: I got 2 stars, but still only have 5 people. How much more do I need to raise it?

Comment: Did you just recently get to 2 stars? It may take a while for extra visitors to show up, but you should have 10 for a 2-star Krustyland. [reference](http://tstotips.com/archives/11786)

Comment: Still waiting... Will report tomorrow